# Multiply by Random # & Print Result

Tags: ios, swift, random, swiftui

Basically, what I am trying to do is create a random number between 0.001 and 0.999, take that number and multiply by the sublotTons (currently just set for 1000.0), and add that number to one other number (still need to add that bit of code) for the final result.

The issue I am noticing when calling out the numbers to display on screen is that my Random Number will show one thing, but the math doesn't work out.

For example, on my screen currently, it says my Random Number is .943. 1000 * .943 should equal 943 for my Random Sample Tonnage, instead it is telling me that is equal to 525.

Could it be that my code is calling the variable randomNumber twice?

Appreciate the help!

```
var randomNumber: Double {
    let ranNum = Double.random(in: 0.001..<1)
    return ranNum
}

let sublotTons = 1000.0

var randomTons: Double {
    sublotTons * randomNumber
}

var body: some View {
    // Display Random Number
    VStack {
        Text("Random Number: \(randomNumber, specifier: "%.3f")")
        Text("Sublot Tons = 1000")
        Text("Random Sample Tonnage: \(randomTons, specifier: "%.0f")")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not related to your question but if your intent is to exclude zero from the results you can use `FloatingPoint` property `nextUp`. And btw Swift is a type inferred language. You can omit `Double` prefix. `var randomNumber: Double { .random(in: 0.nextUp ..< 1) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `randomNumber` is being called twice.
Since `randomNumber` is a computed property, each time you call `randomTons`, it will return a new random value.
So, if your intention is to have the same value used, then I suggest to store `randomNumber` and make `randomTons` a function that receives that stored value:

```swift
    var randomNumber: Double {
        let ranNum = Double.random(in: 0.001..<1)
        return ranNum
    }

    let sublotTons = 1000.0

    func randomTons(_ number: Double) -> Double {
        sublotTons * number
    }

    var body: some View {
        // Display Random Number
        VStack {
            let storedRandomNumber = randomNumber
            Text("Random Number: \(storedRandomNumber, specifier: "%.3f")")
            Text("Sublot Tons = 1000")
            Text("Random Sample Tonnage: \(randomTons(storedRandomNumber), specifier: "%.0f")")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it twice: once here:

```
Text("Random Number: \(randomNumber, specifier: "%.3f")")
```

and then, when calculating randomTons here:

```
Text("Random Sample Tonnage: \(randomTons, specifier: "%.0f")")
```

Comment: Yes and it might be worth mentioning that both `randomNumber` and `randomTons` are so called computed properties and the code attached to them gets executed every time they are accessed. Personally I would skip the first property and move that code inside the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
var randomNumber: Double = {
    let ranNum = Double.random(in: 0.001..<1)
    return ranNum
}()
```

for **randomNumber** to be calculated and stored one time on start and used later in places you need. You already have this value, not needed to create another one variable to store it again.